# How do I disable automatic diacritics?

Tags: windows-10, typing, diacritics

I have been given a new work computer, and it exhibits some additional functionality that is slowly becoming a nuisance.

The computer supports automatic diacritics; for example, if I type an apostrophe, nothing will display on the screen. Instead, the computer waits for my next input. If the next letter supports the ring diacritic, the ring diacritic version of said letter appears. If it does not, both the apostrophe and the letter appear.

For example, if I type `'a`, it prints á.

I am using a HP machine running Windows 10 Professional version 10.0.15063. A colleague has an identical machine, and we have confirmed the same behaviour on his. I can not seem to find anything to do with diacritics in Control Panel, and research has only turned up plug-ins to provide this functionality. How do I disable automatic diacritics?

Comment: What language packs.  Have you asked your IT staff for help?

Comment: @Ramhound, I am the IT staff. The others are just as confused. The only language pack is English (Australia)

Comment: I think this is a very helpful Q&A, thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out my problem *was* in trying to change my keyboard layout. As it turns out, Windows 10 does not give you the option to change layouts; rather, you have a *series* of layouts to add and remove from.

After going to Settings > Time & Language, you are shown your current languages. For me, this only shows "English(Australia)". Click on this option, and select "Options".

From the window that pops up, you are shown a *series* of keyboards. I found I was using both "US" *and* "US International". Clicking on "US International", and selecting "Remove" disabled the automatic diacritics.

Comment: I do not have neither 'time & language' nor 'US International' and the whole thing is just crazy that there is this complex feature that cannot be simply disabled, we instead have to pull random levers and pray that it works...

Comment: This behavior in Windows has been like that for as long as I can remember, and each time I install a new system, it still confuses the heck out of me. Thanks for the detailed steps.

Comment: Windows 11: there can be multiple language packs (i.e. US English and UK English etc) installed. Each may have the `US International` keyboard selected. Add the `US` keyboard, after which you can delete the offending `US International`.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have your keyboard layout set to 'US International'. Changing it to 'US' should fix this.

Comment: This answer pointed me to a solution. Windows 10 does not give you the option to change keyboards; rather, you have a series of keyboards.

Comment: You can turn on the Language Bar and choose which keyboard you're currently using. The Language Bar lives next to the clock on the task bar. Open the Start menu and type "Advanced keyboard settings" and then click "Language bar options" and set it to "Docked in the task bar" to show it. You can also change the hotkeys that change between languages here, which might be what people inadvertently do to lock themselves into the situation where diacritics are automatic.

Answer (score 1):

There's another way to solve this:

- Go to Settings > Devices > Typing [Typing Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRENs.png)
- Scroll down to "More keyboard settings" and select
- Click on Advanced Keyboard Settings then click on 'Input language hotkeys' which should open the [Text Services and Input Languages settings window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVN77.png)

Here you'll see a few key sequences registered to specific input languages and one of the defaults is "Between input languages" set to "LEFT ALT + Shift".

Now... if, like me, your anarchy knows no bounds and you chaotically switch between MacOS and Windows 10 you might find yourself accidentally hitting ALT+Shift when you intended Windows+Shift because your brain is still thinking Command+Shift (yeah... it happens).

So every time I hit ALT+Shift it toggled diacritics. So sometimes when I thought I'd solved my problem by removing the International keyboard thanks to the suggestion above https://superuser.com/a/1236782/1727163 it would suddenly switch to this behaviour.

My simple solution (as someone who very rarely uses accents) was to de-register that key sequence entirely.

Hope that helps someone else (or me from the future hahaha).